# Traduction de « something is in order »

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

Je me demande si la traduction ci-après de la phrase :

> Some definitions are in order now.

est idiomatique ou non. Voici la traduction :

> Certaines définitions sont en ordre maintenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, cela n'est pas du tout idiomatique, à moins que vous vouliez dire par cela « dans l'ordre des choses » et alors la phrase devient une traduction possible (Certaines définitions sont maintenant dans l'ordre des choses).

« To be in order » pourrait être traduit par « s'imposer », « être nécessaire » et quelques autres expressions.

- Certaines définitions sont maintenant nécessaires.
- Maintenant certaines définitions s'imposent.

Les expressions choisies sont particulières au contexte, qui est scientifique; l'idée de nécessité pourrait ne pas être rendue de façon si explicite et on pourrait donner aussi la traduction suivante.

- Il convient maintenant d'établir certaines définitions.

Dans d'autres contextes on pourra utiliser le verbe « s'imposer » qui traduira une certaine note d'humour de l'anglais dans par exemple « A drink is in order now. », ce que l'on peut traduire par « S'impose maintenant un verre pour tout le monde ».